# Create Addin button in New Message Window and Inbox Window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2007

How to create Addin button in New Message Window and Inbox Window of Outlook 2007 using VSTO.

This code adds button to the main window of Outlook 2007.

```
            //Define the existent Menu Bar
            menuBar = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar;

            //Define the new Menu Bar into the old menu bar
            newMenuBar = (Office.CommandBarPopup)menuBar.Controls.Add(
                Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, missing,
                missing, missing, false);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005 with VSTO installed for Office 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found exactly what I need to do..I was about to add ribbon button in both Compose Window and Read message window toolbar. Please see this link. It was very helpful for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/12/15/making-a-custom-group-appear-in-the-message-tab-of-a-mail-item-norm-estabrook.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Link not working